# How to use permutation test in R for a specific column for a specific number of times?

Tags: r, dataframe

Lets say I have the following df:

```
activity        score
1                 2
2                 4
3                 1
4                 6
5                 10
6                 2
7                 3
8                 6
9                 8
10                5
11                6
12                8
```

and I wanted to randomly shuffle every three scores until it hits activity 12 and then restart the loop (i.e. restart at 1 and reshuffle again every three scores until it hits 12, n number of times). How would I do this in R? Keep in mind, the activities cannot move only the scores.

```
Here would be an example of a result df
activity        score
1                 4
2                 2               <- reshuffled
3                 1

4                 2
5                 10               <- reshuffled
6                 6

7                 3 
8                 6               <- reshuffled
9                 8

10                8
11                6               <- reshuffled
12                5
```

Comment: What do you mean? You say you restart and reshuffle the _activities_, where later you specify that the activities cannot move? What do you mean by "every three", do you mirror the end of the series, overlap with a reflection, or just take last 2/1? When do you stop your loop?

Comment: Sorry. Fixed the question. I want to iterate through the loop n number of times and for each nth time, there is a new shuffle every three scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume `dt` is the dataframe,

```r
for(i in 1:100){
  dt[,2] <- do.call(c,lapply(seq(1,12,by=3),function(iter){
    sample(dt[iter:(iter+2),2])
  }))
}
```

Comment: [iter:(iter+2),2], why is it iter +2?

Comment: @Dylan that's per the example provided in your edit. It will take blocks ``1:3``, ``4:6``, etc